# CSS Float/Clear Puzzle (Competing floats)

Tags: css

I took an image and sliced it into three pieces, then floated them to the right, allowing text to flow around them. The HTML looks something like this:

```
<img src="" style="float: right;">
<img src="" style="float: right; clear: right;">
<img src="" style="float: right; clear: right;">
```

It worked fine until I added a sidebar and floated it to the right above my images, like this...

```
<div class="Sidebar" style="float: right;">Text, Menus, etc.</div>
<img src="" style="float: right;">
<img src="" style="float: right; clear: right;">
<img src="" style="float: right; clear: right;">
```

Now the first image (without the clear style) remains where it's supposed to be, but the other two images drop out of sight below the sidebar.

Does anyone know of a way to fix this?

Comment: Have you tried using `clear: right` only on the sidebar, not on any of the images?

Comment: @ John Rutherford: Yes; that had no effect.

Comment: Do you want the text to flow around the images only, or around the images and the sidebar?

Comment: @ Alochi - That's a good question! The sidebar is actually kind of problematic; I'm still trying to figure out exactly how to implement it. At the moment, it's simply floated to the right, and the text does flow around it on the bottom. So I guess I'd like the text to float around both. However, if you know of any alternate solutions (e.g. text flows around images only), I'd like to hear about them.

Answer (score 2):

You should add a container around the 3 images and float it right.

See this **[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/83VjP/3/)**

CODE :

```
<div class="Sidebar" style="float: right;">Text, Menus, etc.</div>
<div style="float: right;">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/fashion-q-g-100-80-7.jpg" style="float: right;">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/fashion-q-g-100-80-7.jpg" style="float: right; clear: right;">
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/fashion-q-g-100-80-7.jpg" style="float: right; clear: right;">
</div>
```

---

EDIT :

To get the same output, you can use a much simpler CSS (without inline styles that are not recomended) :

**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/83VjP/5/)**

HTML :

```
<div>Text, Menus, etc.</div>
<div>
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/fashion-q-g-100-80-7.jpg" />
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/fashion-q-g-100-80-7.jpg" />
    <img src="http://lorempixel.com/output/fashion-q-g-100-80-7.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS :

```
div{
    float: right;
}
img{
    display:block;
}
```

Comment: @ web-tiki - For me, that's a partial fix in that the image displays correctly, but the div I placed the image slices in prevents the text from wrapping around the image.

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom is this what you are looking for? http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/83VjP/13/

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom The second edit has mistakes, use his first html markup and add your text div after 2 floating divs. Your text will float around both elements.

Comment: @vorrtex what mistakes have you seen?

Comment: @ web-tiki - I see, you're placing the floated image slices ABOVE the sidebar. That will require a little customization, but these are special images, so maybe that's the way to go. Thanks.

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom well in fact you don't need to change the order of the  images/sidebar, you can also do this : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/83VjP/19/

Comment: Wow, thanks for all the tips, but nothing's working for me. CSS seems so much simpler than PHP, yet it also seems less logical sometimes. I think the only solution in this case is to use display: none and zap my sidebar on this particular page.

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom do you have an online example I can have a look at?

Comment: OK, you can see what I'm trying to achieve @ http://www.geobop.org/Reptiles.php To see what it looks like with the sidebar, see http://www.geobop.org/Reptiles2.php Note: I've so far previewed it only with Google Chrome, though I think it should look pretty similar in other browsers (except perhaps IE).

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom I had a look at your website... You are using inline styles, try considering putting your CSS in a external stylesheet you'll see it makes things much easier. Second, your website doesn't look like your code in your question. Now what I would do to achieve your goal would be to float the side bar right, wrap all the text in a div and every sliced image in a div with `text-align:right` and set `display:block;` on the slices. Give me a minute, I'll set up a fiddle to show you.

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom this fiddle should get you on the right path : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/pG5hS/7/

Comment: Again, the outer div doesn't allow the text to flow around the image. Nevertheless, it might be the best solution in this case. Thanks for being more tenacious than me. ;)

Comment: @DavidBlomstrom Sorry I forgot about that! here is the solution : http://jsfiddle.net/webtiki/pG5hS/9/

Answer (score 1):

add this in after the div to clear the float completely.

```
<br clear="all">
```